# How to add the different types of graph and charts in my iphone app via using any other api not core-plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, graph, charts

I am using core-plot but i need to use any other api?
please help me by tell the name of different api's which i can use for add some graphf and chart in my app.
     Also need how to customize the look of these graph  E.g. add images in bar graphs 2d pie chart to 3d pie chat etc.

note:if the Question is not according to the rules please tell me in comments or Edit it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use google's chart api -

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: i need api witch i can use in iphone app programing or in objective-c language .